# How to cause image to fade with hover and show text?

Tags: html, css, popup, hover, fade

*Only HTML/CSS solutions please*

I'm working on an online art portfolio. On each page are a number of paintings, organized vertically. Pretty simple.

However, when the cursor hovers over each painting, I want some text to show, either causing the painting to fade a little bit, or the text can appear in a small text box that follows the cursor.

I would post the code I have now, but after much trial and error, I've stripped it back down to simply a div with the img inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do some selector magic. See attached snippet and CodePen.

Next time, please post some of your attempted solutions. No one wants to just write your code for you.

```css
img.fade:hover /* fade out on hover */ {
  opacity:0.5;
}
img.fade + span /* hide spans immediately after images that are set to fade */ {
  visibility:hidden;
}
img.fade:hover + span /* display spans immediately after :hover faded images */ {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<img class="fade" src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/d4473a971038c392b3e4ecb42e013784/tumblr_nlyfpjetVZ1tdg8rso7_500.jpg">
<span>Here is some Text</span>
```

See CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPPqvM

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted, however, how do I place the text on top of the image?
Could I simply place it behind the image, then when the image is made opaque, the text will show?

Comment: Plenty of options. The text can be styled in any way by adding code to the `img.fade + span` option. How you decide to place it "behind" the image is up to you. Maybe a `position:relative;`?